# Utilising drag & drop but unable to replace elements in DIV before placing new content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This one has me stumped, I've looked everywhere but haven't been able to find a suitable answer for my situation, so here goes.

1. I have many tables that are draggable and they can be copied not moved
2. I have many DIVs that can be dropped into.

Dragging and dropping the table into the DIV works fine, the issue I have is if the user decides to drag another table into the same DIV I want it to replace whatever is already in that DIV already, unfortunately at the moment the table just gets appended to the table that's already in there.

I had some code before which actually was working fine in Chrome but eventually I tried it in Firefox and Firefox just kept throwing an error message, then Chrome updated to the latest version and it also began throwing the same error message, seems Chrome decided to follow suit on some security protocol or fixed a bug. I believe I was getting the error 'TypeError variable is undefined' but I have messed with the code a bit now and no longer get that error, however the table is still being appended to previous table if 1 already exists.

I just want to clear the DIV of anything that might be in there already before dropping whatever in there.

Here is the Javascript code:

```
function drop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var armin = ev.toElement;
if($( armin ).find('table').length > 0) {

    var elem = armin.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    $( armin ).parent().parent().parent().parent().empty();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
    elem.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}
else {
    $( ev.toElement ).empty();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}
}
```

I know the code is a bit of a mess and probably because it's a mixture of new code I tried and old code that was working previously, the 'if' statement isn't triggering no matter what I do so I need help.

Here is some HTML:

Draggable table

```
<div  class="week col-lg-1" >
    <table id="1" class="table table-bordered" style="background-color:#000000; color:white;" 
draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <tr><td data-shift="1" style="background-color:#000000;">7am to 3pm</td></tr>
        <tr><td data-shift="1" style="background-color:#000000;">7am to 3pm</td></tr>
        <tr><td data-shift="1" style="background-color:#000000;">7am to 3pm</td></tr>
        <tr><td data-shift="1" style="background-color:#000000;">7am to 3pm</td></tr>
        <tr><td data-shift="1" style="background-color:#000000;">7am to 3pm</td></tr>
        <tr><td data-shift="5" style="background-color:#000000;">X</td></tr>
        <tr><td data-shift="5" style="background-color:#000000;">X</td></tr>
        <tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Droppable DIV

```
<div class="col-lg-1">
    <div class="title">
        User One
    </div>
    <div  class="schedule" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondblclick="innerHTML = '';">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this issue by adding a double click event that clears the div (innerHTML("")), it works fine for  my needs, just a bit of extra work for the person using it

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `appendChild`, call [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) to clear the existing element's children.

```
elem.empty().appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
```

This will remove all existing elements so that your new element will be the only child.

Comment: I'm trying this but it's not doing anything, the table isn't being dropped at all now, or it's being cleared straight away. I tried with this `ev.target.empty().appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));`